# Is there a way to include time zone in IntelliJ File Template Header?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

```
#set($MyName = "Test User")
#set($test = $date)
/**
 * Created by ${MyName} on ${test}-${MONTH_NAME_SHORT}-${YEAR} ${TIME} .
 */
```

I know that Intellij came with a build in velocity apache variables. Is it possible to somehow get the time to be displayed (with timezone) on file creation?